# Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, django-models, wagtail

I try to get all pages of **ProgramPage** where the field **program_types** has a certain **pk**
Everything was fine before I had added this.

```py
program_type = ProgramType.objects.get(pk=1)   
programs = ProgramPage.objects.live().public().filter(program_types__in=[program_type])
```

Here is the full code of **models.py**:

```py
# program/models.py

from django import forms
from django.db import models

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalManyToManyField

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet


@register_snippet
class ProgramType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Program types"


class ProgramPage(Page):
    description = RichTextField(blank=True)
    program_types = ParentalManyToManyField("program.ProgramType", blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('description'),
        FieldPanel('program_types', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
    ]


class IndexProgram(Page):
    program_type = ProgramType.objects.get(pk=1)   
    programs = ProgramPage.objects.live().public().filter(program_types__in=[program_type])
```

after "makemigrations" or "runserver" I get an error:

> raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
>
> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

Comment: change this line `ParentalManyToManyField("program.ProgramType", blank=True)` to `ParentalManyToManyField(ProgramType, blank=True)`

Comment: The issue is your `IndexProgram` class, it's performing ORM lookups when it's being parsed as you are setting class variables (`program_type`) as the results of queries (`ProgramType.objects.get(pk=1) `)

Comment: @Exprator Thanks I've tried it. Unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All pages have a get_context method that is called whenever the template is rendered and returns a dictionary of variables to bind into the template.

```py
class IndexProgram(Page):    
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        program_type = ProgramType.objects.get(pk=1)
        context['programs'] = ProgramPage.objects.live().public().filter(program_types__in=[program_type])
```